# Possible way of checking electron Application Distribution with linux OS

Tags: linux, electron

Is there a possible way of checking the compatible [electron application distribution](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/application-distribution/) with a given OS?

For example if I have Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64, and I am using [electron-v1.8.2-beta.2-linux-x64.zip](https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v1.8.2-beta.2/electron-v1.8.2-beta.2-linux-x64.zip) for creating a Linux distribution. How can I be sure, that I am using the correct distribution packager of Electron?